# Select all rows if COUNT(DISTINCT COLNAME)>1

Tags: mysql

I want to select ALL rows in a table, if even one value in a particular column is different from any  value in the column.
So to check if all the rows are different I first do  a `count(distinct col_name)>1`.

```
| NAME | YEAR_BORN | SCHOOL |  
| Jack | 2000      | A      |  
|Jill  |2001       |A       |
|Jane  |2000       |A       |
```

Since the year born here is different for Jill as compared to Jack and Jane,
I want to display the column as is. If Jill had the same year born as them, I would not want return anything.

How do I now select all rows if this condition is satisfied?

Comment: Sample Input and Desired Output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a subquery in the where clause:

```
select * from tablename
where (select count(distinct year_born) from tablename) > 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oC7gJe4UmhehwPhj5HhDP8/2).
Results:

```
| NAME | YEAR_BORN | SCHOOL |
| ---- | --------- | ------ |
| Jack | 2000      | A      |
| Jill | 2001      | A      |
| Jane | 2000      | A      |
```

Comment: Thank you , that works!! What if I need to do the same thing  but for every school? Should I use a group by school?

Comment: And in the case where I need to pass in the school name? Would I still have to group by or can I just add it in the WHERE condition?

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oC7gJe4UmhehwPhj5HhDP8/6 or https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oC7gJe4UmhehwPhj5HhDP8/5

Answer (score 0):

You can try `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE count(distinct col_name)>1`

Comment: ok. I don't have he's database and phpmyadmin on this system so i couldn't check